# Changing function properties in a list without return

Tags: python, function

I need to write two functions: memorizer and caller:

1. both receive a list of functions as an argument
2. caller function must return a list of functions in an order given to memorizer function
3. code should work as follows:
   f_list=[f1, f2, f3] -> memorizer(f_list) -> shuffle(f_list) -> caller(f_list)

I cant use global variables, imports and the result of the memorizer function is not used, so it is advised not to implement a return statement.

So far I wrote this:

```
def memorizer(functions: list) -> None:
    position=0
    for i in functions:
        setattr(i,'position',position)
        position=position+1
    return functions

def caller(functions: list) -> None:
    functions.sort(key=lambda x: x.position, reverse=False)
    return functions
```

But it doesn't work, do you know how to get rid of this return statement?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: input is a list of functions in a specified order, and the result should be sorted list of function in a order given to memorize function

Comment: the caller function input is a list of the same functions as in memorizer, but in different order